# allow next line on wordpress product exerpt. Tried to use shortcode [br], works on 1st page but not the 2nd page

Tags: wordpress, post, line, break, line-breaks

I follow this blog post (https://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-line-break/) to add a snippet to enable the shortcode [br] so that the product exerpt allows line break.

I have more than twenty products. It works on the first page (https://paste.pics/MQTNP), but when I turn to the 2nd page, the [br] becomes like this: (https://paste.pics/MQTPX). When I return to the first page, all the [br] codes appear (https://paste.pics/MQTV3). It's weird.

I am very frustrated. Anyone can help? Thank you!

What should I add in the code?

```
function line_break_shortcode_callback() {
    return '<br>';
}
add_shortcode( 'br', 'line_break_shortcode_callback' );
```

Comment: in shop page using woocommerce?

Comment: Yes, it is woocommerce. I am using post grid block insteal of shop page because my client doens't like the layout of the shop page. screenshot: https://paste.pics/MQY1X